# Use Snpkit to animate the two controls. As a result, one control executes the animation, and the other one do not move

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I have listed the important code, I have omitted the other irrelevant

```
extension OpenVIPSearchInputView{
    func showSearchBtn(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.proviceButton.snp.updateConstraints {
                $0.leading.equalTo(self).offset(50)
            }
            self.searchButton.snp.updateConstraints {
                $0.trailing.equalTo(self).offset(-200)
            }
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
extension OpenVIPSearchInputView: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        showSearchBtn()
    }
}
```

**I customized this control, and wanted to animate the buttons in it. I updated the two constraints, but only one button was animated after the chase. I'm confused, I don't know what happened.**

Answer (score 0):

Try putting every action to separate UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {}

Comment: And I don't see reason to use self.layoutIfNeeded() for this